# Can I do regex replace in Android with groups from the match?

Tags: android, regex

I'd like to do something like this on Android :

from:

```
*foo* bar*stuff*
```

dest:

```
<b>foo</b> bar<b>stuff</b>
```

In `C#`, I'd create a Regex and replace:

```
string text = "*foo* bar*stuff*";
Regex bold = new Regex(@"\*(.+?)\*", RegexOptions.Singleline);
html = bold.Replace(html, new MatchEvaluator(p => string.Format("<b>{0}</b>", p.Groups[1].Value)));
```

I've read Android's `java.util.regex.Matcher` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) and it says `replace()` method replaces the entire match with a (constant) string. Is there a trick way to replace each occurence with reference to that occurence's group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
"<b>$1</b>"
```

That's C#, but it should be identical in Java. Similarly, `$0` represents the whole match (or `$&` on some flavors)

Comment: @Axarydax - If it's simmilar to Java (or *is* Java), you'd find these links useful: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html , http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you thrown an eye at [MatchResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html)?